# Find all the zeros of $f(x) = x^3 + 3x + 5$ in $\Bbb Z_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

Find all the zeros of $f(x) = x^3 + 3x + 5$ in $\Bbb Z_7$.
I've tried factoring this into multiple forms but I can't seem to find an easy way to find the $x'$s for $x^3 + 3x + 5 = 0$. Any hints or tips are appreciated. Is there any method to do this efficiently for other problems?

Comment: Did you try plugging in values?

Comment: @CameronWilliams no but I figured that would take forever. I can try that really quick.

Comment: @Nid in $\mathbb{Z}_7$, there are only $7$ values you need to try.

Comment: Apart from $0$, $x^3$ only takes on values $\pm 1$ modulo $7$.  So the computations are pretty quick.

Comment: I get that and I already found the answer but I would like to understand if there is a method of factorization that works for say something much larger than this. @AndréNicolas

Comment: Depends on the structure of the polynomial. There are ideas that help for largish primes, but for something small like this try everything reasonable is best.

Comment: @AndréNicolas gotcha. So there isn't really a "one sized fits all" way of doing these.

Comment: @Nid: Not that I know of, but there are probably useful algorithms embedded in various pieces of number-theoretic software.

Answer (score 5):

We're in luck because this is a very small field. We can just test out all the values.

Obviously $0$ is not a root.

$f(1) = 1 + 3 + 5 = 9 = 2 \neq 0$.

$f(2) = 8 + 6 + 5 = 19 = 5 \neq 0$.

$f(3) = 27 + 9 + 5 = 41 = 6 \neq 0$.

$f(4) = 64 + 12 + 5 = 81 = 4 \neq 0$

$f(5) = 125 + 15 + 5 = 145 = 5 \neq 0$

$f(6) = 216 + 18 + 5 = 239 = 1 \neq 0$.

So there are no zeros!

Comment: $6^3=216$ - maybe you were thinking of $14^2=196$? Otherwise, nice answer :) edit:+1

Comment: Woops, you're right. I'll edit that immediately. Arithmetic might be the hardest part about mathematics in general.